# Find ID of element from next li

Tags: jquery

```
Hi how can I find the id from next li
```

I have to li's and I need to access the element from next li. I have used li.next() to get next li. Now How do I find the id of span from 2nd li

I hope I have explained it

Comment: `li.next().find('span').attr('id')`!!!

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two tops, and then you'll know all the basics jQuery has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

As Arun said:

```
li.next().find('span').attr('id')
```

...will give you the `id` of the first `span` inside the next `li`, assuming `li` refers to the current `li` (and is a jQuery object).

Answer (score 0):

check this out, this may help :`nextLi` is next element from that you will get any property of that.

```js
var nextLi = $( "li.sample" ).next();
nextLi.css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ol>
  <li class="sample">First</li>
  <li id="li_2">Second</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ol>

<p></p>
```